# Update an array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Hey does anyone know how to change the zip code for the city ROSEDALE in MongoDB: Here is an example of my database:

````
      {
        _id: ObjectId("56d61033a378eccde8a83555"),
        id: '102-2015-UNIT',
        certificate_number: 10003479,
        business_name: 'SOUTH BRONX AUTOMOTIVE CORP',
        date: 'May 28 2015',
        result: 'Pass',
        sector: 'Tow Truck Company - 124',
        address: { city: 'JAMAICA', zip: '11432', street: "210TH ST", number: "9940" }
      },```

I need to change the zip code of the city ROSEDALE in many accounts in my database.
````

Answer (score 0):

To change the zip code for the city **"ROSEDALE"** in your **MongoDB database**, you can use the updateMany method along with the appropriate query and update operators. Here's an example of how you can achieve it

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  { "address.city": "ROSEDALE" },
  { $set: { "address.zip": "NEW_ZIP_CODE" } }
);
```

In the above example, replace **"NEW_ZIP_CODE"** with the new zip code you want to set for the city **"ROSEDALE"**. The updateMany method will update all documents that match the specified query.

Make sure to replace collection with the actual name of your collection in the database where your data is stored.

Please note that this example assumes you are using the **MongoDB shell**. If you are using a **MongoDB driver** for a specific programming language, the syntax might vary slightly, but the concept remains the same.

Remember to take proper precautions while modifying your database, such as creating a backup beforehand, to prevent any accidental data loss or irreversible changes.

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked!! Do you know where this is in MongoDB docs by chance. I didn't see this anywhere. I appreciate you help.

Comment: NIce to help you. Take a look at the mongodb basics course. There you can find all these basic stuff. 

Link to syntax updateMany: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#syntax